# Estimating the distribution of a very large population of known size and unknown variance

Tags: distributions, estimation, density-function

I would like to estimate the distribution of a very large population of known size but unknown mean and variance.

I cannot assume anything about the shape of the underlying distribution. However, I am certain that the values in the population are non-negative, non-zero integers. I believe that the distribution is naturally lumped in some way discretely rather than being continuously distributed over the entire range. I cannot sample the entire population but I would like to estimate the probability density function. I would also like some level of assurance of the correctness of the estimated distribution.

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of this question http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12134/estimating-the-distribution-of-a-very-large-population-of-known-size-and-unknown/12136#12136